# C++ How To Call A Function With Different Name?

Tags: c++, function, call, wrapper

In c++, I want to want to make a wrapper class. I am using a math library called glm. There are classes in there called glm::mat4 for matrix math and glm::vec3 for vector math. What I want to do is make a class called Vector which can do everything glm::vec3 can.

The problem is, lets say I want to create a wrapper or extra layer over glm::vec3, for my Vector class I would have to rewrite all the functions of vec3 and then inside those function I call the glm::vec3 functions (sort of how any wrapper would work).

So my question is there a way to avoid this cumbersome work?
Is there a way I can use the glm::vec3 as it is but just call Vector instead (name change)?
Is this even possible???

Comment: So what is it? A wrapper (that changes/adds some functionality)? Or just a rename?

Comment: In C++ you can give any type another name with `typedef` or `using`

Comment: So are you just unhappy with the name?

Answer (score 3):

You can alias your type like this:

```
namespace glm {

class vec3 {
// your implementation...
};

} // namespace glm

// create an alias for glm::vec3
using Vector = glm::vec3;
```

And after, using `Vector` will be just like using `glm::vec3`